# Install Yaru theme in Gnome Flashback session on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, gnome-flashback

I would like to install the new Ubuntu theme "Yaru" in the Gnome Flashback session on Ubuntu 18.04

Thank you!

EDIT: It's still in development for 18.04:

https://github.com/ubuntu/yaru

> **Testing Yaru/Communitheme snap on Ubuntu 18.04 (bionic beaver)**
>
> We're currently still developing the theme, but you can try it out for yourself. Be warned though, this is a pre-release alpha state and not (yet) officially supported.

Comment: what have you tried, what is giving you trouble?

Comment: There is a snap package to install Yaru in a regular Ubuntu session, but I don't see it in Gnome Flashback session

Comment: Could you please [edit] your post when you want to clarify something or add information? It’s best to have everything relevant in one place. Additionally, comments may be deleted for various reasons. Thanks.

Comment: Any update of this? Maybe it can be installed as a regular GTK 3 theme on Ubuntu 18.04 and Debian (Gnome Flashback session) Thanks!